# Django update GenericForeignKey after object creation

Tags: django, django-models

Even if I am an experienced developper, I am pretty new in Python/Django, I probably missed to do something or perhaps I am trying to make something impossible...

I'm using Django 3 with Python 3.7

**Summary:**

I have a model A with a GenericForeignKey to a model B or a model C.
When I set the link, the object A might already exist in the database, so I call a "get_or_create" method to reatreive the object if it is already exist or create a new one if it doesn't existe yet.
Just after the "get_or_create", I set the link to an another object.

I tried to set the link with many ways from instance of object A to an instance of object B but every time I have an error, I looked for some examples to know how to set the GenericForeignKey link when the model is already instanciate but I didn't found it.

**What I tried:**

The last version of my code :

For class A :

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.db import models

class A(models.Model):
    # ...

    number = models.IntegerField(
        'Number',
        editable=False,
        default='-1'
    )

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    object_srce = GenericForeignKey(ct_field='content_type', fk_field='object_id')

    objects = models.Manager()

    @classmethod
    def get_instance(cls, p_number):
        a_objects, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(number=p_number)
        return a_objects

    def set_obj_data(self, p_object_srce, p_number):
        self.number = p_number
        self.object_srce.set([p_object_srce])
        self.save()
```

For class B:

```
from django.db import models
from apps.A.models import A
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericRelation

class B(models.Model):
    # ...
    a_objects = GenericRelation(A, related_query_name='object_srce')
    objects = models.Manager()

    def get_a_number(self):
        if self.a_objects is None:
            return 0
        else:
            lo_a_objects = A.objects.filter(object_srce = self).first()
            return lo_o_objects.number
```

Usage somewhere else :

```
b_obj = B()
b_obj.save()

a_obj = A.get_instance(l_number)
a_obj.save()
a_obj.set_obj_data(b_obj,l_number)
```

When I execute the code, I obtain :

```
TypeError at /admin/TC/tc/
Direct assignment to the reverse side of a related set is prohibited. Use object_srce.set() instead.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/TC/tc/
Django Version: 3.0.5
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
Direct assignment to the reverse side of a related set is prohibited. Use object_srce.set() instead.
Exception Location: C:\Users\myuser\PycharmProjects\test_app\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py in __set__, line 546
Python Executable:  C:\Users\myuser\PycharmProjects\test_app\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.2

(...)

C:\Users\myuser\PycharmProjects\test_app\apps\A\models.py in set_obj_data
        self.object_srce.set([p_object_srce])
```

--> I don't understand this error message because I am already use a set() method

Do you have some ideas to solve this problem ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I believe you should set it like this: `self.object_srce = p_object_srce` in `set_obj_data()`

Comment: When I try that, I have thos following error message :
TypeError at /admin/TC/tc/
Direct assignment to the reverse side of a related set is prohibited. Use object_srce.set() instead.

Comment: in your original example, why do you use `.set([p_object_srce]) ` and not `.set(p_object_srce) `?

Comment: If I do .set(p_object_srce) I have the error message 'B' object is not iterable , so I added [ ] to have an iterable object